# scipy ipython Enthought

Tags: python, scipy, enthought

Because I dont have sudo permission in our linux server,
I need to compile scipy and numpy from source.

After several failures(mainly about ATALS), I gave up and installed Enthought Python Distribution Free instead.

However, ever time I use ipython, I will get the following messenger.

**Enthought Python Distribution (free version) -- www.enthought.com
(type 'upgrade' or see www.enthought.com/epd/upgrade to get the full EPD)**

It is annoying. Could I set somewhere so that the info doesn't appear?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to upgrade to full version ;-) Then this message will disappear (and be replaced by another...)

Comment: @ Charles Brunet, i have no dollars,:(

Comment: Building ATLAS isn't that hard, plus you can install numpy/scipy without it, by editing `site.cfg` file, in which case performance will drop by x30

Answer (score 5):

If you have academic affiliation (or tell them you do), they will send you the link to get the full version for free. Don't abuse that privilege!